# Make logstash filter by name

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a log file called "/var/log/commands.log" that I'm trying to separate into fields with logstash & grok. I've got it working. Now, I'm trying to make logstash only do this to the file "/var/log/commands.log" and not any input by doing "if name = commands.log" but something with the "if" statement seems wrong as it skips over it.

```
input{
file{
path => "/var/log/commands.log"
}
beats{
port => 5044
}
}
filter {
if [log][file][path] == "/var/log/commands.log" {
grok{
match => { "message" => "*very long statement*"
}
}
}
}
output{
elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]}
}
```

If I remove the if statement it works and the fields are visible in kibana. I'm testing things locally. Does anyone know what's going on?

EDIT: SOLVED: In logstash, it has to be only [path] instead of all the rest.

Comment: Can you try `event[path]` in the `if` condition

Comment: event[path] instead of [log][file][path]?

Comment: Yes. Did that work?

Comment: I really want to test it but right now I'm facing a different issue. For some reason after I restart logstash and run it again it start it, says "logstash shut down" and exits.

Comment: There is some problem in the configuration then :( How did you start I mean the command

Comment: logstash --path.settings=/etc/logstash/ 

I tried putting the same config as before (copied from here) and it still does it..